# Save User Link And Jump To TransferPage 3s And Jump back User Link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, vue-router

When user click any bouton, that jump to Transfer Page for 3 sec.

and then will jump back to user clicked link.

Schematic：

[image]

HTML:
[image]

Vue:

[image]

Comment: Hi, code images are forbidden. Please use actual code as text.

Answer (score -1):

Portal Page

```
methods: {
    getSiteLink() {
        this.$axios.$get(`/api/site/list`).then(res => {
            var siteLinkData = res.data
            siteLinkData.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
                siteLinkData[index]["url"] =
                "http://localhost:8080/transfer?redirect_url=" + encodeURIComponent(item["url"]);
            })
            this.siteLinkList = siteLinkData || []
        }) 
  },
```

Transfer Page

```
mounted() {
        console.log(this.$route.query.redirect_url)
        console.log('Our life is up up down down down down down...')
        
        var red_url = this.$route.query.redirect_url;
        setInterval(function(){ 
            window.location.href = red_url
        }, 1000);
    },
```

Comment: No, please do not do `window.location.href` since it will nuke the whole Nuxt app. Use the vue-router with a proper `$router.push` rather.